# How to override default http connection timeout while running development server of Django 3.0.3?

Tags: python, django

I am running Django development server and I want to change the default http connection timeout. As per this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736489/django-http-connection-timeout#answer-47601617) link, django github repo [issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/746#issuecomment-331007551) link and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/i1o2yx/django_api_return_502_error_if_api_does_not/) link, I should pass `--http_timeout` argument while running the development server.

But when I try to do that I am getting error
[image]

I am using Django 3.0.3 version. Is there any way to override the default http connection timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Django has no such option for *manage.py runserver*

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/

Those links you provided refer to the Django v1.11 and Daphne as a HTTP server which had this option.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can override the http connection timeout?

Comment: WSGI server embedded in Django is pretty simple and is limited in configuration. What you will use in production will most-likely be Gunicorn + Nginx.

So you could start using Gunicorn in development (it is installed as python package, which is pretty simple) and start your server start command would be: `gunicorn your_app.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -t 180`

Comment: I might only use development server as it has only limited role in the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that argument is added by [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [here](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/17f8a039bc1c9fc51e4e12f03355a999847763a8/channels/management/commands/runserver.py#L36). So you would need to install and use Django Channels I presume.